# Executor service forgets about queued tasks

Tags: java, spring, executorservice

Working with Java 11 and Spring 2.1.6.RELEASE.

Im expierencing an issue where if I send a few records to the topic that this kafka consumer consumes from, everything works as planned. However If I produce A lot of records (a hundred or so) then the executor queues the processing but never actually does the processing. Am I using the executor wrong? I dont think its a kafka issue. Is there a way to query the executor to debug this?

```java
@Configuration
public class ExecutorServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ExecutorService createExecutorService() {
        return Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    }
}
```

```java
 @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.consumer.topic.name}", 
                groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    public void consume(PayrollDto message) {
        log.info("Consumed message for processing:" + message); // this log is hit for all records
        executor.execute(new ConsumerExecutor(message));
    }
```

```java
private class ConsumerExecutor implements Runnable {

        PayrollDto message;

        public ConsumerExecutor(PayrollDto message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            log.info("Beginning processing for payroll:" + this.message); // this log is hit for only some records
            processPayrollList(this.message);
            log.info("Finished processing for payroll:" + this.message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you don’t think it’s a Kafka issue, can you create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) demonstrating this issue using only Java SE? Your question, as it stands, doesn’t have enough information needed to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using pure Java SE `ExecutorService` classes rather than Spring-specific `TaskExecutor` classes.

There is not enough information to diagnose this properly.  (You haven't provide any clear evidence that the tasks have been "forgotten".  Your reported evidence is that they are not executed.  The "forgotten tasks" is only one of a number of possible explanations.)

The only  explanations that I can think of are:

1. Your `processPayrollList` method is not terminating in some circumstances.  It could be deadlocking, going into an infinite loop, waiting forever on some external service and so on.

   If enough (i.e. 10) tasks failed to terminate, then you would run out of threads in the pool, and no more tasks would be processed.  That is consistent with your evidence.
2. Something in your application is replacing `executor` with a different `ExecutorService` object.
3. Something in your application is removing tasks from the queue without executing them.
4. A build or deployment "process" issue; e.g. the code you are running is different to the code you are looking at.  (It happens.)
5. An unreported bug in the Java 11 class library.

Of these, (1) is the most likely (IMO).  Explanations (2) and (3) involve application code that I assume you would have mentioned in the question.  I would treat (5) as *implausible* ... unless you can provide some clear evidence in the form of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

---

> Am I using the executor wrong?

It doesn't *look* like it from the code you have shown us.

---

> Is there a way to query the executor to debug this?

You could take a thread stack dump (e.g. using the `jstack` command) and look at the status of the threads in the pool.

You could also cast `executor` to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and use that API to look at the queue length, the number of active threads and so on.

---

Note that this is not due to the `ExecutorService` being shut down.  If that happened, you would get `RejectedExecutionException` in calls to `execute`.

Comment: I don’t think this is a very helpful answer. Granted the OP has not given us much to work with (vote to close?), but you’re listing many general possibilities as to what could’ve gone wrong, there’s not a lot of actionable stuff here.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar - Please re-read my answer.  It gives one "most likely" explanation, and IMO it is going to be the real one.  And 4 out of 5 explanations are **directly** actionable.